# How to tell if terminal session is running within screen

Tags: bash, gnu-screen, bashrc

When running a bash script, I would like to be able to tell if it is running within a `screen`. Is this possible?

I want this so that `.bashrc` can set the colour of the command prompt depending on whether the sessions is started within a screen or not.

Discovered this link once mine was answered: [How can I tell whether I'm in a screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392618/how-can-i-tell-whether-im-in-a-screen)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Typically, `$STY` will be set.

So:

```
if [ -n "$STY" ]; then
  echo "I'm most likely running under screen"
fi
```

`$STY` is typically what you need to talk to your `screen`. That is used to construct the path of the Unix domain socket used to control `screen` (something like `/var/run/screen/S-$USER/$STY`.

Now, that won't work for instance if from that screen, you `ssh` to another machine. The shell started there won't have `$STY` in its environment, and that wouldn't be of any use to it anyway, since it wouldn't be able to access the Unix domain sockets on your machine.

However, it is possible to query the terminal with an escape sequence to determine its type:

```
if [ -t 1 ] && [ -t 0 ]; then
  s=$(stty -g)
  stty -icanon -echo min 0 time 3
  printf '\033[>c'
  type=$(dd count=1 2> /dev/null)
  stty "$s"
  case $type in
    (*'>83;'*) echo "this is screen"
  esac
fi
```

Another approach, as suggested by  @val0x00ff is to check the value of the `$TERM` environment variable. That value is meant to tell applications what type of terminal they're talking to. It is set by `screen` to something that starts with `screen` (as `screen` can implement different variants of terminals). `$TERM` is passed accross `rlogin`, `rsh`, `telnet`, `ssh`. It's not as guaranteed to work as the above but is simpler and less intrusive.

```
case $TERM in
  (screen*) echo "I'm more than likely running in screen"
esac
```

Like for the previous solution, you may be running in `screen`, but you may not be able to issue commands to it with `screen -X` for instance. However note, that you can pass commands using escape sequences (though it's not enabled by default for security reasons).

Answer (score 5):

When running in screen your `$TERM` environment variable changes to screen. You can check in the script e.g

```
if [[ "$TERM" == screen* ]]; then
  echo "Running in screen"
else 
  echo "Outside screen"
fi
```

That would be one of the approaches. `echo $TERM` outside the screen and again `echo $TERM` inside the screen and see the difference

Comment: My $TERM is set to "xterm". So, this wouldn't work in my case.

Answer (score 1):

I use tmux myself, and this little bit to list sessions only if im not already in a tmux session

```
if [ -z "$TMUX" ]; then
    alias tmuxa='tmux attach -d -t'
    alias tmuxc='tmux new-session -s'
    echo "You're not in a tmux session, create a new one with tmuxc, or attach to one of the ones below with tmuxa"
    tmux ls
fi
```